# How to allow multiple users to see and edit same page in jsf + hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jsf-2

I have a Jsf + Hibernate + mysql application and when two users in two browsers try to enter the same page at the the same time, a query is executed to show a list and hibernate throws all kinds of exceptions about how "collection was processed twice by flush()" or how session has already been closed.

I honestly don't even know where to begin to look, is it a locking problem from hibernate or session handling by jsf?

If it's locking, my jsf bean has dozens of fields that are being used when the page is accessed, should a lock be implemented in every one of them?

Comment: So your DAO/Service layer is not thread safe? That's a different problem which cannot be solved from JSF side on. Get a Hibernate or JPA book.

Comment: You should really add more information - for example: How are you accessing you Hibernate session? Just a guess, you are using the same session for all requests? An [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) helps as well.